# is there any option for use i18n in Next js without sub path or domain routing?

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, i18next

I have tried manyways like we used in React JS i18n and LanguageDetector but its throwing errr in Next JS like below

*#  `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "login" Client: "Anmelden"`*

I'm not getting proper way to use i18n without Sub Path or domain routing in Next JS

I have tried many option but not getting correct way. I want to use i18n with Multiple Languge without using Sub Path or domain routing. it should change language based on language Select option in Next JS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you found a way?